# Can I jump from one case to another in a switch statements?

Tags: switch-statement, break

For switch statements, is it possible to change the value of the switch inside the switch statement so that it can jump around to different cases?
Ex:

```
int w = 0;
switch(w)
{
   case 1:
     doSomething();
     w = 3;
   case 2:
     doSomething();
     break;
   case 3:
     doSomething();
     break;
}
```

Basically what I'm asking is, if I do not place a break statement for a case and I change the value of the switch in the same case, will the code execute both cases?

Comment: Did you try it? Also, why would you want to do something so confusing?

Comment: @Rafe - It's the spirit that counts, why not try?

Comment: Best way : Try debugging your code ... you will come to know what happens :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can change the value inside switch but it will not execute case for new value until you break in the case where you changed the value.

In your case it will not go in any case as there is no case for 0. But if you change to w = 1 then it will go for case 1 and then for case 2 as you do not have break; but it will not go for case 3.

Comment: but doesn't the break statement break from the whole switch statement entirely?

Comment: @Andrew: that's what I'm saying if you use break; then new value will not do anything. And if you do not have break then it will go next case. But in any case with or without break; changing value will not cause automatic call to respective case.

Comment: so basically, if I do not include break in a case statement, the code will execute the case statement corresponding to the new value that I placed to it?

Comment: @Andrew:No. changing value will not cause automatic call to respective case in any situation.

Answer (score 3):

No, it will not change and will not execute new case statement.

Remember that, once ***appropriate*** match is found with the case statement corresponding to a value inside the switch statement, that particular case is executed and once that is executed ( if break is provided after each case to prevent falling through all cases) , then the control returns to the end of switch statement.

**Sample Code :**

```
public  class A {
            public static void main(String [] args) {
                    int i=1;
                    switch(i) {
                            case 1 : 
                                    System.out.println("Case 1");
                                    i = 2;
                                    break;
                            case 2 : 
                                    System.out.println("Changed to Case 2");
                                    break;

                             default:
                                    System.out.println("Default");
                                    break;
                            }

                    System.out.println("Final value of i " + i);
            }
    }
```

**Output :**

```
Case 1
Final value of i 2
```

---

**Note :** Inserting proper breakpoints, try to debug. You will come to know yourself, what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If we do not give break after each case then Java will start executing the statement from matching case and keep on executing statements for following cases as well, until either a break statement is found or switch statements end is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

If `case 1` happens to execute, it's just a **fall through** to the `case 2`. And since there is a `break` in `case 2`, further **fall through** doesn't happen. It doesn't jump to `case 3` because of the statement `w = 3 ;` in `case 1`.

Answer (score 0):

No the switch's case will not change when changing the value in a particular case it checks only once

```
let a = 1
    switch (a) {
      case 1:
        console.log("Hello from 1")//only this will be printed 
        a = 2//value of a is changed
        break
      case 2:
        console.log("hello from 2")//this will not execute
        a = 3
        break
      case 3:
        console.log("hello from 3")//this will not execute
        a = 4
        break
      case 4:
        console.log("hello from 4")//this will not execute
        break
      default:
        console.log("default")
    }
    console.log(a)//value will be 2
```