# Enums and case statements. Not switching even with break

Tags: java, enums, case

I am trying to switch states, starting from the start state. However when I enter input to go either to the fail state or the go state, neither work. I had tried adding breaks into the code as suggested before, but I am afraid it had no affect. Any other solutions?

```
  import java.util.*;

 public class dfa {
  static State state;


 public enum State 
{
    START_STATE,
     GO_STATE,
     FAIL_STATE,
     };

dfa(State state)
 { state = this.state;}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    int number;
    state = State.START_STATE;   
        switch(state)
            {
            case START_STATE:

                System.out.print("In start state \n ");
                System.out.println("Which state you want to go to? \n");
                number = input.nextInt();
                if(number == 1)
                {
                    state = State.GO_STATE;
                    System.out.print(" Go hello");

                }
                else if(number == 2)
                {
                    state = State.FAIL_STATE;
                System.out.println(" Fail hello ");
                }
                break;

                case FAIL_STATE:  
                System.out.println("fail state");
                break;
                case GO_STATE:
                System.out.println("go state");
               break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Default");
                break;
            }


    System.out.println("made it here");





  }

  }
```

Comment: Are you expecting that if you set `state`, then it will automatically go to the next state?  If that's what you're thinking, that isn't what happens.  `switch` executes the statements for a given state, then it exits.  Then, if there's nothing that tells it to go back up to the `switch`, it never looks at the `state` again.  I suspect you want to add a loop, but there aren't a lot of details about what you need to accomplish.  If you do add a loop, make sure it isn't an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already inside of your switch statement when you change the value of `state`, and as shown is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105740/switch-statements), once a match is found that case is executed and control flows to the end of the switch statement.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you want to update `state` and keep enter the switch again you will have to add a loop.