# How are Switch statements used in Java?

Tags: java

I need to input a switch statment in my program and i wanted a clear understanding at where can i break and continue. Its break time and i didnt understand this code; can i get an understading please? I need clear and more informed explanation. I have searched And this is what i got but has not answered my question at what point do we break or continue and again this is what i saw. I need links; ([Switch Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105740/switch-statements))

```
public class SwitchTrying {

   public static void main(String args[]){

      char grade = 'B';

      switch(grade)
      {
         case 'A' :
            System.out.println("Excellent!"); 
            break;
         case 'B' :
         case 'C' :
            System.out.println("Well done");
            break;
         case 'D' :
            System.out.println("You passed");
         case 'F' :
            System.out.println("Better try again");
            break;
         default :
            System.out.println("Invalid ");
      }
      System.out.println("You got : " + grade);
   }
}
```

Comment: What "question" do you have about how the code works or what a switch statement does? Also, make sure to [read/follow tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) and other introductory information.

Comment: I want to know how to use them.

Comment: Well, the posted code is one example. What "question" do you have about it?

Comment: I want several understanding and explanation. I am confused at what point do i break.

Comment: I suggest that you try to figure it out by changing the letter B in `char grade = 'B'` to other letters and seeing what text the program prints when it runs. Then try removing one of the `break` statements and see what happens.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Stack Overflow is not for tutorials.

Comment: My question was do we have an order of breaking the switch?

Comment: I have seen some answers. i will use. Thank you everyone.

Comment: "I want to know to use _X_" is not the kind of question that is encouraged here.  You can almost always find out how to use X by Googling for a tutorial or an example.  Come back to this site when you have written a program that either won't compile, or behaves in a way that you don't understand, and all your efforts to figure out why have been in vain.

Comment: To write structured code (you should always do this), then the break goes at the end of each `case`: before every `case`/`default`, except where a `case` follows a `case`.

Answer (score 2):

Switch statements are are like a series of `if` statements, evaluated in the order they appear in the code. As soon as one of the conditions evaluates `true`, it starts executing all of the code after it until it hits a `break`.

In your example, you pass in grade **'B'**. It first checks `case 'A'`. Obviously a **'B'** isn't an **'A'**, so it skips that section of code (which would print out **'Excellent'**) and checks the next condition. Next, `case 'B'` evaluates `true` because you passed in a **'B'**, so it will now start executing all the code it sees until it reaches a `break`. That means it will print out **'Well Done'**, then it will hit the `break` after that and jump out of the switch statement.

This design means that you can have multiple different conditions execute the same code, like in your example. Both a **'B'** and a **'C'** will print out **'Well Done'** because there is no break in between them.

Answer (score 0):

You need a break at the end of each case block. Otherwise, every case block after the matching one will be executed until a break is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Switch statement above works like as follows:

if grade is "A", app prints "Excellent" and breaks out from the switch statment.

If Grade is either B or C, it prints "Welldone" and breaks out from the switch statement.

If Grade is D it prints "You passed" but since there is no break, app also goes to case F (right below D) and prints "Better try again" and then breaks out.

If Grade is F, app prints "Better try again" and then breaks out.

If any other value for Grade is given, App prints "Invalid".

And finally program prints "You got: XX" .

Since Grade is hardcoded in the program, only B branch works. Try chaning it to other values to see what happens.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Well let me introduce you to switch statements; A switch statement allows a variable to be tested for equality against a list of values. Each value is called a case, and the variable being switched on is checked for each case.

Now Look at the example below; I will use this example;

```
switch(expression){
    case value :
       //Statements
       break; //optional
      case value :
       //Statements
      case value :
       //Statements
        case value :
       //Statements
       break; //optional
    //You can have any number of case statements.
    default : //Optional
       //Statements
}
```

To answer your question at what point does one break note: I have indicated it is optional, hence you can apply a break point anywhere. Now we have several rules for the switch statement.

This might help you understand it more;

> Note 1: A switch statement can have an optional default case, which
>   must appear at the end of the switch. The default case can be used for
>   performing a task when none of the cases is true. No break is needed
>   in the default case.
>
> Note: Not every case needs to contain a break. If no break appears,
>   the flow of control will fall through to subsequent cases until a
>   break is reached.
>
> Note: When a break statement is reached, the switch terminates, and
>   the flow of control jumps to the next line following the switch
>   statement.
>
> Note:The value for a case must be the same data type as the variable
>   in the switch and it must be a constant or a literal.When the variable
>   being switched on is equal to a case, the statements following that
>   case will execute until a break statement is reached.
>
> And always remember: The variable used in a switch statement can only
>   be a byte, short, int, or char

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good tutorial at:

[Switch Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

As a note, however, a grade of 'B' or 'C' will produce the same result. The lack of a break statement in the case for 'B' causes execution to fall through to the next case statement - even though the condition doesn't match. The way it's written, it's like an 'OR' statement.

A value of 'D' will print "You passed" as well as "Better try again", also because of the lack of a break statement.

Take a look at the tutorial.

Good Luck!